# Trying to add a background to a twitch channel with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, twitch

Twitch.tv used to offer its users the ability to upload a channel background, but has long since removed this feature. I've been trying to add it back, and been unsuccessful.

This is what I am working with here, from twitch:

Note: the ember### and data-bindattr-###="###" change often, so I didn't bother trying to tag those.

```html
<div id="ember841" class="ember-view" data-channel="jimieo">
  <div class="content" data-bindattr-857="857">
    <div id="channel">
      <script id="metamorph-26-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <script id="metamorph-26-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <script id="metamorph-27-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <script id="metamorph-28-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <div id="ember872" class="ember-view"></div>
      <script id="metamorph-28-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <script id="metamorph-27-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <div class="player-column host-frame js-host-frame" data-bindattr-874="874"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to use the following to get it to work:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#data-channel=jimieo > div#channel").prepend("<canvas height="1080" width="1920" image="i.imgur.com/5su8sTX.jpg"></canvas>");
});
```

The end result I was aiming for was this...

```html
<div id="ember841" class="ember-view" data-channel="jimieo">
  <div class="content" data-bindattr-857="857">
    <div id="channel">
      <canvas height="1080" width="1920" image="i.imgur.com/5su8sTX.jpg"></canvas>
      <script id="metamorph-26-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <script id="metamorph-26-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <script id="metamorph-27-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <script id="metamorph-28-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <div id="ember872" class="ember-view"></div>
      <script id="metamorph-28-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <script id="metamorph-27-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <div class="player-column host-frame js-host-frame" data-bindattr-874="874"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but just tested it works via browser console.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("<style type='text/css'> .js-directory, tse-content { background: #000000 url('http://i.imgur.com/5su8sTX.jpg') no-repeat fixed center !important; } </style>").appendTo("head");
});
```

Comment: Where did you get those class names?  Also, there is a missing `.` with the 2nd one. Finally, `$(document).ready` is almost never needed in GM scripts. (Only needed when `document-start` is set.)

Comment: Just via Inspect Element and messing about, As I said its probably not the best way to do it but it works, I have not worked with GM scripts before

Comment: @Gav I appreciate you taking the time to help. 

I was unable to get this one to work on my end. I was able to get the black background to show though. Just not the image itself.

Comment: I should mention I was using BTTV, I forgot to say that maybe it has something to do with why it works for me and not you?, I'll disable it and work on it.

Comment: Ahh.. I didn't think of that one. I haven't used BTTV in a while, switched to FrankerFaceZ. Thanks @Gav